# How to make sure that when you load the map it is always in satellite type automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to make my map when it loads always appear in satellite type which does not work for me, not if the line of my code is wrong.

this is my code:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 center: {lat: 9.150598, lng: -79.242535},
 zoom: 17,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
 });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using a static string instead of the variable/const `google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE`?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 center: {lat: 9.150598, lng: -79.242535},
 zoom: 17,
 mapTypeId: 'satellite'
 });
```

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes this should work.

Comment: Have you tried it with the constant? According to the documentation, both should work. And both work.